# Machine learning applied to geometry

Tags: machine-learning, geometry

before i have to say that i don't know very well machine learning.

I want to ask if with Machine Learning can help to fill a specified area with some irregular geometries to use more area that it can, it's call "nesting"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Machile learning works by comparing the current configuration to other ones previously shown for training, with solutions, and tries to "interpolate" between them.

In your case, it means that you should have sufficiently many solved cases so that you can reasonably cover the configuration space. This can be a serious obstacle, because it requires that you have a packing algorithm anyway.

Also, due to the discontinous nature of the solution function, I doubt that an ML approach be efficient and able to construct collision-free solutions in all cases.